# RStudio/R - Sorting dataset by length of characters instead of row

Tags: r, dataset, rstudio

I have a huge (30mb) text document of random usernames. It looks like this:

- a0hrszq13k
- a0huod_cv4q
- a0hxyaszqfk
- a0hz
- a0i5dk349

So on and so forth...

I want to sort these so that it will show me a list of names that are below a certain number of characters. For example let's say I wanted to know all the names that have less than 5 characters, using the small segment of data above, I would know that the only answer would be "a0hz". How can I get R to compute this itself and display the results?

First time I've asked a question so feel free to ask a follow-up question if this is unclear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll want to check out this post on reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Once you read in your data as a character vector (called `names` in my example), you can do it like this:

```
> names <- c("bill", "bernice", "bob", "beatriz")
> names[nchar(names) < 5]
[1] "bill" "bob"
```

Comment: But if I have thousands of names, would I have to put each name in parentheses? Or can I just do this: > names[nchar(names) < 5]? @Reed

Comment: No, you just need to read your data into R; at that point you'd use the solution I gave above. Here's a good site on importing data to R: http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame/data-import. You'll want to look at ```read.table()``` in particular. If you need more help, feel free to post another question with an example of the text in your file

Comment: I'm trying to reformat this my apologies....  My code I used `code> names  = read.csv("b_2765605.csv") > names [nchar(names) < 4] data frame with 0 columns and 2765604 rows(There was already 2765604 rows in my original dataset so it looks like something went wrong)`

Comment: I'm sorry it's very difficult to learn how to position the text correctly... I even read the markdown doc and I'm messing it all up.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but this is pretty basic stuff in R. It's probably better for you to take a couple hours and work through an intro course, for example, tryr.codeschool.com. In the meantime, you could try this: ```names <- read.csv("b_2765605.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[, 1]; names[nchar(names) < 5]``` It will work if all of the usernames are in the first column of your CSV file.